# Is there a PDF version of the Castle Windsor documentation?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, castle-activerecord

The only documentation I've found for the components of the Castle project I've found [here](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v1rc3/index.html) in the form of online HTML files.  Does anyone know of anything that is more off-line friendly or printable (e.g. PDF).  I've got quite the long train commute and I'd like to put something on my laptop. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Decker, I've wondered about the same thing (not only for Castle Windsor) for many Web based resources.  Offline usage.  I wonder whether there's a tool that could create Web Arcive files (MHT) files by crawling the links on a web page.  I'm sure there must be one in the wild...

Update:

I [Googled](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1T4ADBS_enUS293US296&q=offline+web+to+MHT+tool) and found 
[this](http://www.internet-soft.com/extractor.htm).
Sure an Open Source version should be available somewhere.  Let me know if you find it :)

Comment: There is, but since I don't use them to pull down porn websites, I have absolutely no idea what they are.  But I'm sure if you search sourceforge you'll find a few of them...

Comment: @Will:  I'm doubt if Castle site has links to Porn ;)

Comment: I've converted some sites for offline reference with httrack (http://www.httrack.com/) and an html to pdf converter.  But that is on Linux, there should be a Windows equivalent for the conversion and HTTrack has a Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mirror of that site for offline browsing using Wget.

http://wget.addictivecode.org/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Answer (score 0):

You can download it right from the Castle SVN repository and browse if offline:

http://www.castleproject.org/community/getinvolved.html